# Use powershell to export list of AD members for every security group in local AD container into csv file

Tags: powershell, csv

I have been working on this for some time and I keep getting close but then run into issues so I am turning to you knowledgeable folks.

Here is what I am trying to do exactly:

-Export a list of users for each group in our Active Directory container

-The CSV file needs to be organized so that each list of members are labeled with the associated group they are a member of.

-Only the name of the user and the security group they are a member of is needed.

Here is the script that I have been working off of:

```
$csvfile = "c:\users\*name*\desktop\ADGM.csv"
$grouplist = Get-content "C:\users\*name*\desktop\AD Groups Audit\ADG.txt"
$SamAccountName = $grouplist | foreach-object {
    get-adgroup -filter "name -eq '$_'" | Select-object -Expand SamAccountName
    }
Get-ADGroupMember -identify $grouplist | select samaccountname
$csvoutput | sort-object samaccountname | export-csv -Path $CSVfile - NoTypeInformation
```

2 things that I have noticed but just wanted someone to confirm.
Since I have the list of groups already referenced in line 2, do I need lines 3-5 since it appears to be attempting to perform the get-adgroup action?

I get an error when I run the script as-is.  The error refers to the search filter indicating that 'get-adgroup -filter "name -eq '$_'" | select-object -Expand SamAc ... "The search filter cannot be recognized".

For the exported CSV file, if possible, I'd like to have each group created in a new tab.  If it can label the tabs that would be ideal but if not, not a big deal.  Otherwise, a long list with the group name dividers dividing each list.

TIA

Comment: The syntax of your search filter is good. Is there are blank line in your `ADG.txt` file? Each line needs to be a group name and nothing else like extra line breaks, empty lines, etc.

Comment: You are wanting to do things with a CSV that `Export-Csv` can't do. You will want to consider something like the [ImportExcel module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/7.1.0).

Comment: There was a space before the start of the list of samaccountname.  Deleted that space and ran it again and still returned the same error calling out the search filter.

I did install the ImportExcel module as well.

Comment: What does `$grouplist -contains ''` return?

Comment: If by return you mean running that command in PS, then it returned 'True'

Comment: Since I don't know what `ADG.txt` looks like, you can just run `$grouplist = $grouplist -ne ''` before `SamAccountName = .... `

Comment: Still throws the "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'identify'.  Ive tried -identify samaccountname and -identify $grouplist with no success.

Comment: The parameter is `-Identity` not `-Identify`

Comment: Okay, yep Im an idiot.  So I changed it to -Identity and got a new error.
Cannot convert 'System.Object [] to the type 'Microsoft .ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup' required by parameter 'Identity'.  Specified method is not supported.

Do I need to add a -search base and the path to our AD container so that it knows where to look?

Comment: That means that you are passing an array to the command, so try to loop through the array one at a time with `foreach` or something similar.

Comment: @NekoMusume I'm still relatively new to PowerShell so bear with me.  What do you mean by passing an array and loop through the array one at a time?

Comment: `$SamAccountName` is going to be an array of group `samaccountname` values. You need to loop through those and send each to your `Get-AdGroupMember` command like `$SamAccountName | % { Get-AdGroupMember -Identity $_ }`

Comment: Like @AdminOfThings said, the resulting class of the `$SamAccountName` variable will be an array since there would be multiple values. The example @AdminOfThings gave is sufficient but an alternative could be `ForEach ($Account in $SamAccountName) {Get-AdGroupMember -Identity $Account}`

Comment: You have a typo in the parameter: `-identify` --> `-Identity`